# Restoring backup with a MySQL Database downgrade

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.1, wordpress, downgrade

I want to migrate a MySQL 5.7 database to a MySQL 5.1 version because the MySQL version of the server I’m migrating my WordPress webpage is 5.1. I tried to do it in the usual way but it was not possible. Moreover, I read on this webpage:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.12/en/restore-upgrade.html

that restoring to an older MySQL version should only be performed when the original and the final server versions are in the same release series.

I was wondering what other options I have besides creating the WordPress webpage from scratch using the MySQL 5.1 version this time.

Comment: Have you tried logical dump restoration ?

Comment: I doubt if there is any difference that would prohibit 5.7 from handling source code expecting 5.1.  One thing that could bite you is the use of new keywords, but most of WP avoids names that could conflict.

Comment: Did you read https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/ ? It says: "MySQL version 5.6 or greater OR MariaDB version 10.1 or greater. "

Comment: and mysql5.1 was EOL since December 4, 2013 see: https://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html

Comment: Copy data using SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE and LOAD DATA INFILE. They are version-independent.